# need assistance with a simple python error

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, syntax-error

I'm trying to make a very simple program. I have made one similar to this and it worked. however this one is giving me the error. The second button in the code is where the error speaks of.  I have no idea whats wrong. I'm new to programming. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
AttributeError: App instance has no attribute 'h_one'
```

My code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()


        self.button = Button(
            frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit
            )
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5)


        self.hone = Button(frame, text="Happy #1", command=self.h_one)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=BOTTOM,pady=5)


        self.htwo = Button(frame, text="Happy #2", command=self.h_two)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=BOTTOM,pady=5)


        self.hthree = Button(frame, text="Happy #3", command=self.h_three)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=BOTTOM,pady=5)


        def h_one(self):
            print "1"

        def h_two(self):
            print "2"

        def h_three(self):
            print "3"

frame=Tk()
frame.title("Mad Mike's Happy Tool")
frame.geometry("360x400+200+200")

label0 = StringVar()
label0.set("MMHT")
labelA = Label(frame, textvariable=label0, height = 4)
labelA.pack(side=BOTTOM)





app = App(frame)


frame.mainloop()
frame.destroy()
```

Comment: Look at your indentation; see how `h_one` and the other methods are indented *further* than the `__init__` method? Try to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to define your h functions inside of the class **init** function.
Try backing the def h_... functions one indentation level out, like so.

```
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()


        self.button = Button(
        frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5)


        self.hone = Button(frame, text="Happy #1", command=self.h_one)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=BOTTOM,pady=5)


        self.htwo = Button(frame, text="Happy #2", command=self.h_two)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=BOTTOM,pady=5)


        self.hthree = Button(frame, text="Happy #3", command=self.h_three)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=BOTTOM,pady=5)


    def h_one(self):
        print "1"

    def h_two(self):
        print "2"

    def h_three(self):
        print "3"
```

Comment: Yes that was it, thank you both for the fast responses. Sorry it was such a simple question i asked. i just thought it looked right. Thanks!